# Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined (rxJS - Subscription)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to get a grip of subscriptions and observables in rxJS.

I want to change the interval of an Observable by unsubscribing and then resubscribe using the new interval setting.

Should be really simple but since I'm a beginner in this area I could need some assistance.

See this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/AcT2hd)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Observable Interval - Changing interval';
  currentTime: any;
  refreshInterval: number = 1000;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private timeService: TimeService) {
  }

  clicked($event) {
    console.log('new refreshInterval: ' + this.refreshInterval);

    // Here I would like to unsubscribe to the subscription 
    // and then resubscribe using the new interval. 
    // However using below statement causes a 
    // TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    this.getTime();
  }

  // with this implementation changing the refreshInterval won't have any affect. 
  getTime() {
            this.timeService.getTime(this.refreshInterval)
              .subscribe(t => {
                this.currentTime = t;
              }
            );
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.getTime();
    console.log(this.subscription);
    console.log('refreshing each ' + this.refreshInterval + ' ms');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the subscription within the `getTime` method:

```
getTime() {
  return this.timeService.getTime(this.refreshInterval) // <-----
          .subscribe(t => {
            this.currentTime = t;
          }
        );
}
```

In your case, nothing is returned. That's why you have an undefined error...